# What is the fastest and most efficient way to learn to make a marketplace?

Tags: python, html, css, django, marketplace

I am currently recovering from an injury and will be stuck in bed for the next 2 months, and I will use all my time awake learning to code a marketplace.

What is the fastest and most efficient to learn to build an online marketplace, from scratch?

What do I need to know?

Where can I get that information?

My background in computer science is scarce. I have completed the Python course on Codecademy, as well as the HTML/CSS course. Searches say Django is beginner-friendly and rapid to prototype.

Thanks beforehand

Answer (score 2):

This question is so going to get flagged by someone though I'll give you a fair answer even if it isn't what you expect.

I write all my own software from scratch so I can tell you this: pick a scripting language, a database, XHTML as application/xhtml, use CSS and JavaScript and never use frameworks if you want higher quality/lower overhead. If you use frameworks you will trade off getting stuff done faster but end up with a lot more maintenance as well as a much weaker understanding of the code.

I program PHP and use MySQL though Oracle (evil) bought out Sun Microsystems (Good) so I'll be migrating to PostgreSQL because Oracle is slowly killing off MySQL. PHP is very well documented and you can very quickly start coding by setting up a [XAMPP server](https://www.apachefriends.org/) locally. When you look something up on php.net you simply add the command, e.g. [php.net/explode](http://php.net/explode).

You will not have a working product in two months unless you go heavily framework and like I said you will be very burdened by maintenance. If you have a long term commitment then you will have to reinvent the wheel but if you attack all the things that make people swear at their computer then you'll be able to ultimately be much more responsive (you're in control, not someone else's code) with your software to future clients which would give you a serious edge.

Either way whatever you amount of time you think you can build something double it. Don't know how to program? Double it and then multiply it times ten unless you're exceptionally gifted/get lucky.

Be warned: your question is very close to, "How do I build a Facebook?" which is something I would just walk away from people. Start your concept small and work on the most fundamental critical goals only, get them ironed out and then expand outwards.

Comment: John I like your answer but your forgetting a few things. If you create something from scratch your will make mistakes. hundred, thousands of mistakes and you will start repeating yourself (inserting something in your database). Oh, wait your will use the principle `DRY`? (Don't Repeat Yourself) So you create a nice class that will handle your database actions, how about dynamic urls? another nice class, displaying images? Rendering templates? I could go on but that will not fit in a comment. Using a framework can and will help you develop your website.

Comment: Btw I use Django as a Framework. Sure Django is heavier then Flask (also Python) but it does wonders when you know how to use it. I do agree with John `Start your concept small and work on the most fundamental critical goals only, get them ironed out and then expand outwards`. So don't try to invite the wheel again and use a framework for what it is designed for! Helping the developer

Comment: @Eagllus - `So you create a nice class that will handle your database actions, how about dynamic urls? another nice class` ... man, I keep updating my dom after stuff changes, and triggering actions when the user interacts with my dom ... lemme write a nice class to provide a binding between my objects and the dom ...

Comment: And why not just use a framework that already have created that class for you and most likely flexible, less bugs and a broader used for many different cases. But I'm not here to tell you, you shouldn't create your own framework. I have created many many many frameworks and trying will make you as a beter developer! And maybe someday I will use your framework (if it's opensource ofcourse)

Answer (score 0):

It depends how much customization, full on control you want. If you want to go with ecommerce platforms (since your background is not in CS), you can check out Shopify, Magento, Wordpress and Woocommerce. Otherwise, John has a good answer and Python/Django is definitely a good choice in that respect.